# counting the number of residues in a file

Tags: awk

I have a file as follows. I would like to count the number of each character.

```
>1DMLA
MTDSPGGVAPASPVEDASDASLGQPEEGAPCQVVLQGAELNGILQAFAPLRTSLLDSLLVMGDRGILIHNTIFGEQVFLP
LEHSQFSRYRWRGPTAAFLSLVDQKRSLLSVFRANQYPDLRRVELAITGQAPFRTLVQRIWTTTSDGEAVELASETLMKR
ELTSFVVLVPQGTPDVQLRLTRPQLTKVLNATGADSATPTTFELGVNGKFSVFTTSTCVTFAAREEGVSSSTSTQVQILS
NALTKAGQAAANAKTVYGENTHRTFSVVVDDCSMRAVLRRLQVGGGTLKFFLTTPVPSLCVTATGPNAVSAVFLLKPQK
>1DMLB
DDVAARLRAAGFGAVGAGATAEETRRMLHRAFDTLA
>2BHDC
MTDSPGGVAPASPVEDASDASLGQPEEGAPCQVVLQGAELNGILQAFAPLRTSLLDSLLVMGDRGILIHNTIFGEQVFLP
LEHSQFSRYRWRGPTAAFLSLVDQKRSLLSVFRANQYPDLRRVELAITGQAPFRTLVQRIWTTTSDGEAVELASETLMKR
ELTSFVVLVPQGTPDVQLRLTRPQLTKVLNATGADSATPTTFELGVNGKFSVFTTSTCVTFAAREEGVSSSTSTQVQILS
```

I tried the following code.

```
awk '/^>/ { res=substr($0, 2); } /^[^>]/ { print res " - " length($0); }' <file
```

The output  of the above code is

```
1DMLA - 80
1DMLA - 80
1DMLA - 80
1DMLA - 79
1DMLB - 36
2BHDC - 80
2BHDC - 80
2BHDC - 80
```

My desired output is

```
1DMLA - 319
1DMLB - 36
2BHDC - 240
```

How do I change the above code for getting my desired output?

Comment: Best to avoid `< file`. You will loose access to some built-ins like `FILENAME` for example.

Comment: Did you test all the solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk '/^>/ && r { print r, "-", s; r=s="" } /^>/ { r = substr($0, 2); next } { s += length } END { print r, "-", s }' file
```

Results:

```
1DMLA - 319
1DMLB - 36
2BHDC - 240
```

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
awk -F\> '/^>/ {if (seqlen != ""){print seqlen}printf("%s - ",$2);seqlen=0;next}seqlen != ""{seqlen +=length($0)}END{print seqlen}' infile
```

Or formatted:

```
awk -F\> '/^>/ { if (seqlen != "")
                    print seqlen
                 printf("%s - ",$2)
                 seqlen=0
                next } 
          seqlen != ""{seqlen+=length($0)}
          END{
             print seqlen}' infile
```

see:
[Sequence length of FASTA file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23992646/sequence-length-of-fasta-file/23992773#23992773)

Apart from the expected result, this will handle these unexpected file formats.

```
$ cat infile
MTDSPGGVAPASPVEDASDASLGQPEEGAPCQVVLQGAELNGILQAFAPLRTSLLDSLLVMGDRGILIHNTIFGEQVFLP
LEHSQFSRYRWRGPTAAFLSLVDQKRSLLSVFRANQYPDLRRVELAITGQAPFRTLVQRIWTTTSDGEAVELASETLMKR
ELTSFVVLVPQGTPDVQLRLTRPQLTKVLNATGADSATPTTFELGVNGKFSVFTTSTCVTFAAREEGVSSSTSTQVQILS
NALTKAGQAAANAKTVYGENTHRTFSVVVDDCSMRAVLRRLQVGGGTLKFFLTTPVPSLCVTATGPNAVSAVFLLKPQK
>1DMLB
>2BHDC
MTDSPGGVAPASPVEDASDASLGQPEEGAPCQVVLQGAELNGILQAFAPLRTSLLDSLLVMGDRGILIHNTIFGEQVFLP
LEHSQFSRYRWRGPTAAFLSLVDQKRSLLSVFRANQYPDLRRVELAITGQAPFRTLVQRIWTTTSDGEAVELASETLMKR
ELTSFVVLVPQGTPDVQLRLTRPQLTKVLNATGADSATPTTFELGVNGKFSVFTTSTCVTFAAREEGVSSSTSTQVQILS


$ awk -F\> '/^>/ {if (seqlen != ""){print seqlen}printf("%s - ",$2);seqlen=0;next}seqlen != ""{seqlen +=length($0)}END{print seqlen}' kk2
1DMLB - 0
2BHDC - 240
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -vRS='>' '$1{gsub( "[\r]", "",$1 ); 
              printf "%s - %d\n", $1, length($0) - length($1) - NF + 1}' input
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on what changes you made and how that works for future reference?